# Add an option to highlight the focused LayoutItem(DevExpress VCL)

Tags: delphi, devexpress, vcl

In the WinForms LayoutControl you have a feature to highlight the whole LayoutItem when its control is focused. Does anything similar exist for the VCL dxLayoutControl?

Answer (score 0):

I use FocusControlOnItemCaptionClick to highlight the LayOutItem.

```
<TdxLayOutControl>.OptionsItem.FocusControlOnItemCaptionClick:= True;
```

Comment: ,FocusControlOnItemCaptionClick is not my goal

Comment: Explain more what your goal is in place of downvote my answer. You can place your request to devexpress.

Comment: if <TdxLayOutControl>.Customization is true then you can customize the layout and the layoutitems are highlighted with a rectangle arround the item.

Answer (score 0):

You can use each components StyleFocused.Color property to make the active/selected component have a different background.

Something similar to:

```
  for I := 0 to self.componentCount - 1 do
  begin
   IF SELF.Components[i] is TcxCustomEdit then
   if not (Self.components[i] is TcxGroupBox) then //optional
      TcxCustomEdit(Self.components[i]).StyleFocused.Color := claqua;
  end; // for
```

The drawback is that this will require the components transparency to be false - which means you could also get the background of each object a slightly different color to the layoutcontrollers background color.